# How to skip warning "Your Windows 7 PC is out of support"?

Tags: windows-7

With the [Update KB4530734](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4530734/windows-7-update-kb4530734) a full-screen notification will appear that describes the risk of continuing to use Windows 7 Service Pack 1 after it reaches end of support on January 14, 2020 on Windows 7 Start, Home Basic, Home Premium, Professional, Ultimate.

[image]

How can I prevent showing it up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To skip the warning starting with January 15, 2020, click on label `don't remind me again`

[image]

or apply this registry change, by creating a new text file with the following content:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\EOSNotify]
"DiscontinueEOS"=dword:00000001
```

save it as `DiscontinueEOS.reg`, make a double click on `DiscontinueEOS.reg` to import the changes.

Now the message never appears on the Windows 7.

Comment: I want to upvote this as a good answer to the question… but I want to downvote it because Win7 is going the way of XP [cry cry] & Vista [who even noticed?].. but it's going & will no longer be safe.

Comment: Quote from ZDNet "Those who see the full-screen warning will have three options: Remind me later; Learn more; or Don't remind me again. If users don't click on the "Don't remind me again" button and just dismiss the screen, they will continue to get nag warnings"   So you can set it not to remind you again

Answer (score 0):

I have found another way to do this.

First go to the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options` then create a new subkey named `eosnotify.exe`.

Now create a new REG_SZ value named `Debugger` and set value to `Block`.